# Apache Spark, find the largest value for a key value pair?

Tags: apache-spark

How to find the largest value for a (k,v) for a given RDD ?

I tried the following:

```py
RDD.map(lambda (k,v): (k,v)).takeOrdered(1, key=lambda x: -len(x[1]))
```

Is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Have you tried using the `max` method on RDD?

Comment: Justin's solution is good and the shortest possible. As a more general alternative, you can just `r.reduce(Math.max)`, that is, you just repeatedly replace any pair of values by the largest of them both, until only one remains.

Comment: I haven't. Yea its better alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 JavaRDD<String> input = sc.textFile("README.md");
 JavaRDD<Tuple2< Integer,String>> tupleRDD = input.map(new Function<String, Tuple2<Integer,String>>() {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<Integer, String> call(String v1) throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2< Integer,String>(v1.split(" ").length, v1);
        }
    });
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<Integer,String>> tupleRDD1=  tupleRDD.sortBy(new Function<Tuple2<Integer,String>, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call(Tuple2<Integer, String> v1) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v1._1;
        }
    }, false, 1);
    System.out.println(tupleRDD1.first());
```

here i have read a file and split it on space and stores it in a map with number of words as key and line itself as value. and then used first value of map(Integer) to sort the same in descending order. In this way first element of rdd is of highest length.